# Although only half of a dish is red, can I call it ‘red dish’?

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-language

Although only half of a dish is red, can I call it ‘red dish’? Or only when an entire dish is red, can I call it ‘red dish’?

Comment: Although none of it is truly happiness, can I call it a Happy Meal?

Comment: If it's at least half red, I think it would be fair to call it "reddish"

Comment: Language is largely imprecise, and most precisions depend on the subject (on who refers to the object). There are no rules on subjective preferences. Who determines if you can, or cannot, are the subjects of the group where you use such language. So, you should ask your family, not here.

Answer (score 0):

From philosophical logic perspective, your question may be worth further studied in fuzzy logic which I'm not versed in and cannot say much.

From philosophical ethics point of view, it depends on your intentions. Since you're already aware of only half of the dish is red, if you want to share this info for others to identify this dish, you should describe as accurately as possible. If you use it as a trope for your newly minted poem or rap, based on your rhythm constraint, you may omit some info, or call it anything else which may sound more fit...

Answer (score 0):

Of course. If the rest is colorless then why do you hesitate to call by its colour?

Eg: If you put a few drops of ink in a glass of water and it will turn colourful. **To specify** this water you may use its colour even if only few drops are coloured. In the case of a dish, even if the main part of it is red and another color is visible, we cannot call it a red dish.

Another case:

If only red is visible then we can call a dish a red dish.

One more case:

Suppose the visible part is alike (other than red) and the hidden part of one, red. Even if red colour is less than half, the chefs who prepared can specify it by the hidden color. They know what’s hidden below.

Since your idea cannot be transacted 'through the dish', there is not much philosophy in this question. Otherwise there is possibility.

Answer (score 0):

If the other half of the dish is blue, and you wish to distinguish it from a set of dishes which are completely blue, then it would make sense to call it the "red dish". However, the label could be misconstrued by others to mean the dish is completely or mainly red if the appropriate rationale is not provided for the label.